# Measure resistance (make connection) between array of points

Tags: addressing

I have array of connectors where I will plug in various types of resistors, I would like to be able to connect to each of the points as addresses and measure resistance between these points. Here is an illustration to make it clearer:
[image]

I have used serial encoders to pass I/O data to a array of points, but this is a bit different. The resistance part in this question is irrelevant, question is more about connecting two points together. What IC could be relevant, what should I search for to learn about this topic? I have heard a term 'multiplexing' - would that be relevant to this problem ?

Comment: Look up analog MOSFET switches.  When ON they have a resistance.  Turn on two points, apply voltage, measure current.  Repeat.  Multiplex between different points via switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure, such as silicon substrate resistances, using analog multiplexors, you'll need KELVIN 4-wire measurement.

I remember my confusion the first time I ohmed out the resistance between various pins (I had 7 GND and 7 VDD, for RF signal fidelity) on silicon. Turns out the #substrate-connections (or the #well-ties) has a huge effect on resistance. The distance between various regions.......not so important.

[image: schematic]